# how to restore backup from rsync

Tags: rsync, backup-restoration

I want to restore a backup.
With respect to rsync I have a doubt

If the server A on which I have to restore backup from a USB disk
I do as follows

rsync -avz /usb/disk -e ssh root@IP:/

will it over write all the files on server A with the ones on my USB
(which is what I want also)
or I need to do some thing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, if you for example backed up /var/lib/mysql, and its now in /usb/disk/mysql, it'll be backed up to /mysql. If you however backed up /var, and it's /usb/disk/var, it'll overwrite /var.
copy it to a temporary directory first and be very careful in the process of rollback.